# JMS Exception what type of exception is this?

Tags: java, jms

I am getting the following error when running my code in production. But the same doesnt happen in the qa environment or the dev environment. I am thinking that this might be a problem in the jndi name. But i am not 100 percent sure. Can anyone tell me what will cause this exception?

```
 org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 203  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.writeErrorSend(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.writeErrorSend(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.writeLock(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.finishSendingRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(Unknown Source)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.narrowContext(Utils.java:126)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:94)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:31)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:41)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the symptoms of this Java bug - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6553303

If this is the problem, then the fix is to upgrade the JVM on your production boxes to a more recent version.  The bug report's closure details tell you the minimum patch level (for Java 5 & Java 6) you need fo the fix.